# How to set up https only on one directory of VirualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http, https, openssl

I have VPS with several sites and applications, and I want to run MySQL administration tool over https to avoid possibility of man-in-the-middle attack, since I often have to use mysql root password.

Now, it would not be problem at all if I had domain name specially for that purpose, since it's no problem to set up ssl virtual host. My task is to make only one (sub)folder of default virtual host https-forced.

Let's say I have `/var/www` with vhosts folder and everything below. If i type http://{ip-adress-of-vps} i get file that serves as index for `/var/www` which is default host. I want to create `phpmyadmin` dir below `/var/www` (`/var/www/phpmyadmin`) and to access it via https only when calling `http://{ip-adress-of-vps}/phpmyadmin`.

**Is that possible?
How to do that?
If not possible, what's your best practice?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you add a domain name? You already have a VPS, so don't you have some kind of domain control? You could make a subdomain like phpmyadmin.domain.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible in apache.  The SSLEngine is enabled per virtual host.

What you need to do is create an additional virtual host, and create a specific directory block for the directory you want to work like this.  Deny all access to it.  Then, use mod_rewrite to redirect users to the HTTPS URL when they query that part of the site with HTTP.

A better solution is to use a separate domain name for your secure content.